# Can I acknowledge a close colleague for the good time I had with them?

Tags: thesis, masters, acknowledgement

I am finishing the redaction of my master's thesis and writing the acknowledgment section. I was wondering if it is common and professional to thank close colleagues for the good time you had with them?

Comment: Just don't use the words "the good time you had with them". It may not be understood in the way you intend.

Comment: I don't think that whether you do it or not, or how exactly you do it, will have any impact. As marker of master theses I'm not interested.

Comment: @JackAidley I didn't see it that way, I will formulate it differently in the thesis

Answer (score 3):

As the commenters have already pointed out, your (non-academic) acknowledgments probably won't have much impact on anything. One option I've seen a lot is to thank people "for their support" to cover more emotional bases without getting soppy.